# Create organisational database in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am wondering how to best structure a database that holds data on employees, their departments and their managers.

The problem I have is that it essentially needs to be infinitely recursive as there could be multiple departments underneath each other.

So, just like a folder structure essentially.  But how can I best save this data into a mySQL table or tables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at Merise Method

Comment: A `FOREIGN KEY` referencing to its own table is what you are looking for

Comment: Have a look at Bill Karwins great slides on hierachical data in a relational database: https://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: @Cid that is what I currently have, although I don't see how I am able to get a full structure with that setup.#

Comment: You have to use it from bottom to top. the foreign key referencing the parent element. if you want to get all child elements of the entry with id `42`, you can use that kind of where clause `WHERE parent_id = 42`

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 separate tables `department` and `employees`.

Each employee will have a `department_id` and a `manager_id`.

Let's say the topmost person in the organization is a CEO. He will have a department and his manager id will be zero.

Then comes CTO, CFO, etc. They will have a department too and a manager id which will be that of a CEO.

Likewise, you can built the entire system by adding the foreign key reference in the same table `employees`.

Similarly, to maintain the hierarchy of departments you can create a column `parent_department` as a foreign key reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the Departments table you'd need an extra column like "parent ID" which would be the ID of the Department above it in the hierarchy (if any).

A table is allowed have a foreign key to another column in the same table.